# Malicious Downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes

Two downvotes within 5 seconds of each other on two separate threads...seems intentional.  What can be done?

[How can I reorder a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177590/how-can-i-reorder-a-list-in-python/2177607#2177607)

[python chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179241/python-chaining/2179265#2179265)

Comment: You might just be unlucky today. :( I had one user downvote me twice in two separate threads because he thought my answers were vague, but he removed both downvotes when I edited for clarity. This was all possible because of the @targeted comment notification.

Comment: yeah...if there were comments i would (and do) certainly respond to them.  will circle back once more to double check for any.  sorry it happened to you too.

Comment: If only there was a way to force a comment on downvotes...

Comment: Yeah...and it's spreading.  More downvotes.  Ugh.

Comment: If it's all the same person and there are a sufficient number of downvotes, the votes will likely be detected and removed by the suspicious-voting-patterns script.

Comment: Comments explaning downvotes should be mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flag the moderator to check on it.  They're quite helpful.

Comment: How do I flag a downvote?

Comment: You flag the question.