# Targeted "malicious" downvotes

Tags: support, voting, voting-anomaly-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serial Downvoting Victim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim)

I appear to have been the target of a spate of what certainly appears to be malicious downvoting over on SO, [One question on here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37862/malicious-downvotes) suggests that I should flag this to a moderator by flagging one of the questions I've been downvoted on, but given that I didn't actually ask any of the questions concerned, I want to be sure that's the correct thing to do.

If anyone who is a moderator happens to see this, and can indeed do anything about it (as it seems a bit crap that some perfectly valid answers will now hold less weight in peoples eyes - the rep loss, I care not about! :), I suspect that the user concerned has an ID of 21xx54 and has ejected their toys from the pram on the basis of a comment I made on an answer of there's (since deleted) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371638).

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756

Comment: As with any other group, Stack Overflow users include some not very nice people. We've got takers and aggressive jerks and passive-aggressive jerks. Heck, some of them a pretty good users most of the time and only exhibit poor behavior occasionally. Try not to let them get to you.

Comment: @dmckee, Oh, I don't, I also don't give a monkeys about the rep. I gained that all back in a single answer five minutes ago :) I'm more annoyed at the way it's devalued some answers...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems [the best answer has already been given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/serial-downvoting-victim/28758#28758) as Downvoter mentioned in his comment.

For those too lazy to click through:

> There are three ways to fix it:
>
> 1. Do NOTHING. The daily vote anomaly script will pick it up and
>      your rep will be recalculated
>      automatically.
>
> If after 36 hours (give the script
>   time to run) you still see a problem,
>   then:
>
> 1. Flag one of your posts and ask for a rep-recalc
> 2. Contact team@stackoverflow.com and they'll run a rep-recalc

Comment: Who would downvote this answer?? Maybe it will be fixed in the recalc?

Comment: @Hogan: If your comment is referring to the CW status of my answer, I did that because I don't think I should garner rep on a duplicate. I only answered to provide an answer if it wasn't marked as duplicate, and for those lazy souls who would have never clicked the link to the duplicate.

Comment: @Hogan: If your comment is referring to the fact that someone actually downvoted it, all I can say is: who knows why, hell if I care. They probably (rightfully, at least in part) are upset that I answered a duplicate.

Comment: Senior: It's OK, this is Meta. Duped answers are not frowned upon (specially since you gave the link to the original *and* made wiki). On S[OFU] you'd have a point, but here rep points are as meaningless as in *Whose line is it anyway!?* Maybe the downvoter thought that the do-nothing approach was a bad one? May be his finger twitched? Who knows. Who cares.

Comment: Actually it was a joke -- given the question topic and all.  Sorry if I caused confusion.